# How to sum up duration in one column based on simillar date in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, group-by, jupyter-notebook

| Date | Name | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.23 | John Adams | 14:52 |
| 01.01.23 | John Adams | 15:02 |
| 01.01.23 | Stacey Roland | 29:47 |
| 01.04.23 | Ron Swanson | 30:22 |
| 01.05.23 | Jan Wood | 28:48 |

I am trying to get a new df where the values in the Duration column are summed up if the name and the date are the same.

The result should look like this

| Date | Name | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.23 | John Adams | 29:54 |
| 01.01.23 | Stacey Roland | 29:47 |

I tried using groupby but I don't seem to fully understand how it works.

df = df.groupby('Date').sum()

did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) you first need to convert your Duration strings [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then you can [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
out = (df.assign(Duration=pd.to_timedelta('00:'+df['Duration']))
         .groupby(['Date', 'Name'], as_index=False).sum()
      )

print(out)
```

*NB. assuming `14:52` is `MM:SS`, for `HH:MM` you would need to convert with `pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration']+':00')`.*

Output:

```
       Date           Name        Duration
0  01.01.23     John Adams 0 days 00:29:54
1  01.01.23  Stacey Roland 0 days 00:29:47
2  01.04.23    Ron Swanson 0 days 00:30:22
3  01.05.23       Jan Wood 0 days 00:28:48
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01.01.23', '01.01.23', '01.01.23', '01.04.23', '01.05.23'],
                   'Name': ['John Adams', 'John Adams', 'Stacey Roland', 'Ron Swanson', 'Jan Wood'],
                   'Duration': ['14:52', '15:02', '29:47', '30:22', '28:48']})
```

Comment: For some reason the Duration column is not returned. Only Date and Name remain

Comment: Did you assign the output? Can you provide a reproducible input as I did in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach without `.assign()` but also using [**`.to_timedelta()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [**`.groupby().sum()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), which might seem simple.

```py
df["Duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Duration"])
df.groupby(["Date", "Name"], as_index=False).sum()
print(df)
```

---

```
       Date           Name        Duration
0  01.01.23     John Adams 0 days 00:29:54
1  01.01.23  Stacey Roland 0 days 00:29:47
2  01.04.23    Ron Swanson 0 days 00:30:22
3  01.05.23       Jan Wood 0 days 00:28:48
```